# Running VCC-compiler failed

Tags: varnish

Whenever I am running the command sudo service varnish restart it shows the following message

```
* Stopping HTTP accelerator varnishd                                    [fail]
* Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                    [fail]
```

Message from VCC-compiler:

```
Expected '.' got 'sub'
(program line 98), at
('input' Line 11 Pos 1)
sub vcl_recv {
###-----------


In backend specification starting at:
('input' Line 7 Pos 1)
backend default {
#######----------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
```

my default.vcl file is

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }
}

# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_fetch {
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
}
# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
# sub vcl_recv {
#     if (req.restarts == 0) {
#   if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
#       req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
#   } else {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
#   }
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" &&
#       req.request != "HEAD" &&
#       req.request != "PUT" &&
#       req.request != "POST" &&
#       req.request != "TRACE" &&
#       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
#       req.request != "DELETE") {
#         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
#         return (pipe);
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
#         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
#         /* Not cacheable by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (lookup);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hash {
#     hash_data(req.url);
#     if (req.http.host) {
#         hash_data(req.http.host);
#     } else {
#         hash_data(server.ip);
#     }
#     return (hash);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fetch {
#     if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
#         beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
#         beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
#       /*
#        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
#        */
#       set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
#       return (hit_for_pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_deliver {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
#     <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_init {
#   return (ok);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fini {
#   return (ok);
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your configuration file. You need to fix that.

```
Expected '.' got 'sub'
program line 98), at
('input' Line 11 Pos 1)
```

means that the error is in line 11 of the configuration file (using a editor which displays line numbers can be very useful):

```
  1.  # This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
  2.  # man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
  3.  #
  4.  # Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
  5.  # server.
  6.  #
  7.  backend default {
  8.      .host = "127.0.0.1";
  9.      .port = "8080";
 10.  # Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
 11.  sub vcl_recv {
 12.          if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
 13.                  unset req.http.cookie;
 14.         }
```

Seems that at line `11.  sub vcl_recv {` somebody is trying to define a VCL subroutine within a backend specification, which is not a valid syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Close the Backend:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
**}**
```

Comment: What value does this answer provide beyond the existing answer?

Comment: Just pointing out what cause the syntax error